# Equivalent of configuration profiles (iOS) for Android, Windows Phone 7 and Blackberry

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry, mobile

In iOS, configuration of email, wifi and vpn etc. can be pushed over the air using Configuration Profiles. Is there anything equivalent for Android, Windows Phone 7 and Blackberry?

Link to Configuration profiles for iOS 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH1-SW1

Comment: What you have found for these devices so far?

Answer (score 1):

Look to the BES technology for BB. Everything is controlled by Service Records. But I don't know way to push/install custom Service Records. But I think there is definitely some way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for [OMA DM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_DM) which can be used to manage a device similar like the apple profiles. The OMA DM framework is currently not part of Andoid, but some mobile device manufacturer, for example Samsung with the [Galaxy Note](http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/mobile-phones/mobile-phones/galaxy-note/GT-N7000ZBADAM-spec) or Motorola with the [BRAVO](http://mediacenter.motorola.com/Fact-Sheets/Motorola-BRAVO-Fact-Sheet-343b.aspx) added it to there firmware. Microsoft Windows Mobile also used [OMA DM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737369.aspx). According to the ATT Website Windows Phone 8 also supports [OMA DM](http://developer.att.com/developer/device_detailSpec.jsp?id=10500009).