# Android equivalent to iOS Configuration Profiles to update app's settings

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In `iOS` you can email users a [Configuration Profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)
XML file that will automatically update custom app-specific settings when opened on the device with the app installed.  This is an easy way to get configuration settings to many users who use your app so they don't have to manually enter them.  For example, this could update or enter a URL to a web service needed for the app to work.

You don't need an MDM, you can just email the file as an attachment.

Is there a similar way to do this with `Android`?  I've found some of these Android interfaces and APIs but they don't seem to accept updates by opening a file on the device from what I see:

[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[RestrictionsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/RestrictionsManager.html)

[Managed Configurations](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html)

[Device Administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

I don't want to use an MDM or external URL listening.

I checked these questions but they were either not exactly the question or old so I don't know if there is a new way that it can be done:

[What is iOS mobile config equivalent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998870/what-is-ios-mobile-config-equivalent-in-android)

[Android Config File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140539/android-config-file)

[Equivalent of configuration profiles (iOS) for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942896/equivalent-of-configuration-profiles-ios-for-android-windows-phone-7-and-blac)

[Android remote or push config profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011757/android-remote-or-push-configuration-profile)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just have the app register a custom URI or file format via Intent Filter? You would be still responsible for securing/validating the payload.

Comment: Emailing a file of settings?  That seems incredibly insecure.

Comment: @GabeSechan  No sensitive data is in the configuration file.  Apple supports this, maybe in Android it's not a good idea.  I'm not really an Android developer so I don't know.  This is from the iOS Developer documentation I linked in my question: There are five ways to deploy configuration profiles:
-Using Apple Configurator 2, available in the App Store
-In an email message
-On a webpage
-Using over-the-air configuration as described in Over-the-Air Profile -Delivery and Configuration
-Over the air using a Mobile Device Management Server

Comment: @MorrisonChang  I'll look into custom URI or Intent Filter, as long as they can load the custom app settings after the app is installed it might work.

Comment: I'm working on an Android WiFi configuration. This following link looks promising. It would only work for WPA-Enterprise (username+password or client certificate). https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-passpoint